# Inserting SQL Server Results into Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:
[image: Sample]

Where the Student Name, Student ID and Classification are, I would like to fill that with the results from a SQL Server view.  The columns to the right (Capstone, Milestone 2, Milestone 1, Benchmark, Semester Grade, Notes) will remain blank until the instructor fills them in later.  These columns will not be written back to the database but will be saved, with the data that is loaded from the database, into the first three columns in it's Excel spreadsheet format.

Question 1:  Is there a way to simply "embed" the data that is coming from the view?

Question 2:  If not, can you provide a link to an example using a macro to read records and insert them (moving lower rows down with each new record)?

TIA

Comment: I hope those are pseudonyms. I'd feel sorry for Lexie Lombard.

Comment: Do a search for `ADO VBA Excel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use VBA to create an ADO connection, recordset, command, and parameter.

```
Dim adostudent as ADODB. (...) ^ use the above
```

Then, assign a named range to the areas that you would like to drop the information

StudentRow

Then, use a Do Until and an iterator and do until.eof and .movenext to drop the values from the recordset into the range.

```
irow = 10 'insert the header row # + 1here
Do Until adostudent.EOF = True
with adostudent
StudentRow(irow,1).value =.Fields("Student Name").value
...
...

.movenext
irow = irow + 1
loop
```

Comment: This is, basically, what I ended up doing.

Thanks to all for your help and suggestions.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

On the Data tab in Excel you can select "From Other Sources" icon from the "Get External Data" group to pull your student data from a SQL Server view.

That will give you the "embedded" data, until you decide to Refresh your connection and retrieve updated data from the view.

EDIT:

Use the CopyFromRecordset method for Range objects. Here is the link that provides working examples for what you are trying to accopmlish, without the range being being pushed to the side. Entries #3 and #11 provide the VBA examples.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=217783

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Data->Get External Data->From Other sources->From SQL feature in Excel.

Or use my Add-In:
http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-sql-add-in-free/

Comment: "Get External Data" doesn't so much embed the data as it inserts the data.  Basically it just shoves all the existing columns over (in my example above, the "Reflections on the report" area should fall below the last record of the data, but it is shoved over).

Comment: This is a bad answer, and kinda seems like advertising.

Comment: My answer is totally relevant to the question and i not violating any rules as the link is also on topic. What a wrong way to promote your own answer...

Comment: Actually get external data will insert a reusable query and problems with shoving rows is a matter of leaving many empty rows hidden before the summary rows. E.g. Hide as many rows as needed after query refresh

Comment: I didn't say it was irrelevant, it is relevant, but still a bad answer. Also, after 4-5 attempts at your link, I still can't open. So, basically, assuming your blog does not work for others, your answer is basically "Open a connection." 

No discussion of how to insert the values into the table in the correct manner(which was the actual question), only a single line of mouse clicks to !open! only the first part of the process that the question needs.